How to write boldface Greek text in latex while using times package
I want to write upright bold Greek letters (not in math mode). I also want to use the times package for the entire document. I used the following code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}  % Babel for language switching
\usepackage{times}
\newcommand{\ga}{\greektext a\latintext}
\newcommand{\gb}{\greektext b\latintext}
\newcommand{\gp}{\greektext p\latintext}

\begin{document}    

Bold beta: \textbf{\gb}

Normal beta: \gb

\end{document}

, but could not succeed. If \usepackage{times} is made inactive, the desired result is obtained, but not in Times font. Seeking a solution.

The times package is outdated. You shouldn't use it.

Complementing the comment of @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, the successor to times is mathptmx.  But it does not make any difference for your case.
By the way, the greek characters that you get are not in "Times" font but in Computer Modern (greek) font. I do not think there is a "Times" greek font for pdflatex.

I am not aware of Times fonts suitable for Greek either. You could try Libertinus with \usepackage{libertinus}. Btw. I find your commands \ga, \gb clumsy:  you could code Some latin text, \textgreek{abcdefgh}

@nplatis there is also the (even more modern) newtxtext package, but it also lacks Greek glyphs.

Use a Times clone that supports Greek, such as Tempora.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}  % Babel for language switching
\usepackage{tempora}
%\usepackage{newtxmath} % uncomment if you need math

\newcommand{\ga}{{\greektext a}}
\newcommand{\gb}{{\greektext b}}
\newcommand{\gp}{{\greektext p}}

\begin{document}

Bold beta: \textbf{\gb}

Normal beta: \gb

%%% better alternative

Bold beta: \textbf{\textgreek{b}}

Normal beta: \textgreek{b}

\end{document}


Note that switching back to \latintext isn't necessary if you use braces.
